# Enable button when passwords are alike

Tags: jquery

So I just figured out how to check out if my 2 password inputs are alike. Now, what I want to do is when the passwords are alike, I wanna enable the submit button. This is what I've come up with:

```
$("#pass2").keyup(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#pass1").val() !== $("#pass2").val()) {
            $(".nosamepass").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".password").css("border", "1px solid #ff0033");
            $('#postPass').attr('disabled', 'true');
        } else {
            $(".nosamepass").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".password").css("border", "1px solid #232323");
            $('#postPass').attr('disabled', 'false');
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

The button is disabled by default.

But fore some reason, the button doesn't enable. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/cmjf9kos/1/ (I have made some adjustments to your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have put `false` in a string it needs to be

```
$('#postPass').attr('disabled', false);
```

also same with your `true` clause fix it as well

```
$('#postPass').attr('disabled', true);
```

full working code would be

```
$("#pass2").keyup(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#pass1").val() !== $("#pass2").val()) {
            $(".nosamepass").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".password").css("border", "1px solid #ff0033");
            $('#postPass').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $(".nosamepass").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".password").css("border", "1px solid #232323");
            $('#postPass').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

working jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/joshstevens19/cmjf9kos/3/

Comment: Im very sory, but the button doesn't enable?

Comment: if that has fixed your issue please mark as accepted so others can find this issue and find a solutions quickly :) @RobinBerg

Answer (score 1):

There is no `false` or `enabled` value for the `disabled` attribute in `HTML`, i.e, there is no `disabled="false"`

Either use

```
$('#postPass').removeAttr('disabled');
```

or

```
$('#postPass').prop('disabled', false);
```

Also, for disabling, you need to set it to `disabled`

```
$('#postPass').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

---

```
$("#pass2").keyup(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#pass1").val() !== $("#pass2").val()) {
            $(".nosamepass").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".password").css("border", "1px solid #ff0033");
            $('#postPass').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $(".nosamepass").fadeOut('slow');
            $(".password").css("border", "1px solid #232323");
            $('#postPass').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: yes there is .attr('disabled', true) is a valid way to do it

Comment: no i down voted you because true false can be used with jquery disabled and he was not asking about html.

Comment: ok well take out your first line or rephase and i will un-down vote you as i think it is misleading for this question.